# protobuf-net How to avoid crashing when working with Indexed Properties

Tags: protobuf-net, indexed-properties

I'm trying to integrate the awesome protobuf-net into an existing codebase, but am encountering a crash when it tries to handle a custom type.  A small demonstration is below: it will throw an `InvalidOperationException` in `ProtoBuf.Serializers.ListDecorator`.  But if you comment out the indexer (or remove the IEnumerable implementation) then it runs cleanly.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ProtoBuf;
using System.Collections;

[ProtoContract]
public class MyClass : IEnumerable<int>    
{
    [ProtoMember(1, IsPacked = true)]
    public int[] data { get; set; }

    // Comment out this indexed property to prevent the crash
    public int this[int i] { get { return data[i]; } set { data[i] = value; } }

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator() { foreach (var x in data) yield return x; }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }

    static void Main(string[] args) { Serializer.PrepareSerializer<MyClass>(); }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?  How can I tell the protobuf-net Serializer to just ignore that Indexer property?

Thanks!

**EDIT** (Oct 10):  Marc has kindly provided a fix in [protobuf-net r447](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/list) via `[ProtoContract(IgnoreListHandling = true)]`.

Comment: btw; `[ProtoContract(IgnoreListHandling = true)]` will do this; r447 is now available for download

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your type looks suspiciously like a collection, and protobuf-net is indeed trying to handle it as such. One "fix" would be to add an `Add(int)` method, as *that* is what it is going to want to use when deserializing. I am, however, investigating why the presence/absence of the indexer makes a difference here (that is not immediately obvious to me).

Note that *because* this looks so much like a collection, the `[ProtoMember(...)]` might not be used here. I'm not 100% certain until I find out what role the indexer is playing here.

---

Ahah; k; found why the indexer is getting involved - essentially, after detecting `IEnumerable`, it is trying to identify the `Type` of the collection; it uses various cues:

- the `<T>` in `ICollection<T>`
- the `SomeType` in `Add(SomeType)`
- the `SomeType` in a `public SomeTime this[int index] {...}` indexer

of these, the only one that applies is the last. However, IMO it should probably also use the `<T>` in `IEnumerable<T>` (I might tweak this) - this would at least make this scenario less bizarre (as would improving the error message, which I'll do).

To summarize, protobuf-net has lots of very particular handling for things that smell like collections; personally, I'd drop the `IEnumerable<T>` support, and let callers go via `.data` instead; the message will (at some point) display:

> Unable to resolve a suitable Add method for {FullName}

Comment: Thanks.  The real-world type is actually an ArraySegment<T> kind of thing, showing a limited view of the underlying array.  So the implementation of IEnumerable<T> doesn't simply expose the Array.  Those "cues" are in TypeModel.ResolveListAdd(), right?  I might try to hack that a bit...

Comment: @Gabriel it is `GetListItemType` that is at fault here

Comment: Ah, yeah, I see that now.  Thanks!

Comment: @Gabriel to clarify, my preferred option here is to figure out some mechanism to say "this really is a single object; ignore all list handling", rather than fuss with that method

Comment: Perhaps something like a `bool NotAList` property in the `ProtoContractAttribute` ?

Comment: @Gabriel something like, indeed; noting, however, that the attributes are only a thin veneer in v2 to steer the `MetaType`, which is where it ultimately needs to be possible. I'll add somet' ;p